# Using a colon as a separator in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var data = "needactivation:9";
if (data.indexOf(":") == true) {
    replyData = data.split(":");
    if (replyData[0] == "needactivation") {
        alert("User Id Is " + replyData[1]);
    }
}
else if (data == "success") {
    window.location.href = "/";
}
else {
    alert("Unknown error.");
}
```

Is my JavaScript. It should alert the User ID but it gives a unknown Error. Any idea whats wrong with this script?

Not sure if this part matters, but i'm using the latest jQuery on the page also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns an index (or `-1` if not found), not a boolean. Change this:

```
if (data.indexOf(":") == true) {
```

To this:

```
if (data.indexOf(":") !== -1) {
```

Alternatively, you could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) regardless and then check [`replyData.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Answer (score 2):

`String.indexOf()` returns a number >= 0 when the string is found, not a boolean `true` value

Your test should read:

```
if (data.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "needactivation:9";
if (data.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
    replyData = data.split(":");
    if (replyData[0] == "needactivation") {
        alert("User Id Is " + replyData[1]);
    }
}
else if (data == "success") {
    window.location.href = "/";
}
else {
    alert("Unknown error.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (data.indexOf(":") != -1) {`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to verifying that the above answers are correct, I just wanted to say that you may also want to employ some kind of try/catch logic once you've changed your `true` to `-1` since a string like `Anything:` will have an `indexOf(":") >= 0` but will split in such a way that your reference to `replyData[1]` will throw yet another error.